# Great grandchild route won't activate

Tags: angular, router

I am trying to activate a component by url "/Recruitment/Application/2/ApplicantDetails". I am using angular@5.0.0

The routes:

Parent route

```
        {
            path: 'Recruitment', loadChildren: 'ngModules/dashboard/RecruitmentDashboardModule#RecruitmentDashboardModule',
            canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        },
      {
            path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent,

            }
        }
```

Child

```
   RouterModule.forChild([
        { path: 'Application/:applicantId', loadChildren: '/ngModules/recruitment/RecruitmentModule#RecruitmentModule', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ])
```

Grand child& great grandchild

```
    {
    path: '', component: RecruitmentComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'ApplicantDetails', component: ApplicantDetailsStageComponent },

        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'ApplicantDetails',
            pathMatch: 'full',
        },
    ]
}
```

If I pass "/Recruitment/Application/2" into browser,the last redirectTo will be triggered and the url will be changed to "/Recruitment/Application/2/ApplicantDetails" , but the component won't be ApplicantDetailsStageComponent and  the 404 page will be loaded instead.

The "RecruitmentComponent" is getting loaded fine (if I remove the redirectTo), and I could extract ":applicantId" in it.

Does anyone sees anything obvious?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in "  pathMatch: 'full'," I removed it from children routes and everything started to work.